# Formulating Boolean Queries on Lemur Indri

Tags: information-retrieval, lemur, indri

I am unable to write the following boolean query, using Indri Query Language. THe query I need to write is the following:

```
(Stana or Katic) AND (Jon or Huertas) AND (co-stars or colleagues)
```

I need the list of all documents, containing the above. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question on SourceForge, where the author helped me solve this.

```
#band(#syn(Stana katic) #syn(jon huertas) #syn(co-stars colleague))
```

For more information, see the original discussion [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/lemur/discussion/836442/thread/c84b0938/).